# how make my siblings elements render a black color when hovering an element?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working with CSS with Reactjs. I got two sibling element  : my logo and a text beside.
I'm trying to make than when I'm hovering the logo the text become black. 
So far I have don't succeed.

I have tried to share the className, but it fails.

Here my file.js :

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <div className={style.logo_flex}>
      <div>
      <Link to="/"> 
      <img className={style.logo}  src={Logo} alt=""/>
      </Link>
      </div>
      <Link to="/"> 
      <p className={style.brandName}> Coding </p>  
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here my file.css:

```
/* Logo */

a{ 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
}
a:active{ 
    border:none; 
}

a:visited{ 
    color:grey;
}


.logo_flex{ 
    height: 100%;
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center; 
}
.logo_flex:hover{
    color:black;
}
.logo{      
    left: 7%;
    top: 0.2em;
    height: 2.2em;  
}


p, div { 
    display: inline-block;  
}

.brandName{ 
    margin-left: 1.2em;  
    align-self: center;
}

.brandName:hover, .logo:hover{ 
    color:black; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You may not need Pseudo-classes. You can try like below.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            logoClass: 'logo',
            brandClass: 'brandName',
        };
    }


    handleHover = e => this.setState({ brandClass: 'brandNameHover' });

    render = () => {
        const { logoClass, brandClass } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className='App'>
                <img className={ logoClass } src={ 'test' } onMouseOver={ this.handleHover } />

                <p className={ brandClass }>Coding</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `background-color` in `logo_flex:hover`. A simplified version of the corrected program is here.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="logo_flex">
      <div>
        <img
          className="logo"
          src=""
        />
      </div>
      <p className="brandName"> Coding </p>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Style:

```
a{ 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
}
a:active{ 
    border:none; 
}

a:visited{ 
    color:grey;
}


.logo_flex{ 
    height: 100%;
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center; 
}
.logo_flex:hover{
  background-color: black;
}
.logo{      
    left: 7%;
    top: 0.2em;
    height: 2.2em;  
}


p, div { 
    display: inline-block;  
}

.brandName{ 
    margin-left: 1.2em;  
    align-self: center;
}

.brandName:hover, .logo:hover{ 
    color:black; 
}
```